# Expected value for $X, Y \sim \mathcal{U}[0,10]$ vs. expected value of $E(2x)$

Tags: probability

$X, Y$ are independent events both $\sim \mathcal{U}[0,10]$.
I know that $$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y] = 5 + 5 = 10$$
and $$E[2X] = 2 E[X] = 10 \Rightarrow E[X+Y] = E[2X].$$

However, is $E\left[(X+Y-10)_+\right] = E\left[(2X-10)_+\right]$ ? 
I believe the answer is no, but why?

Answer (score 1):

The right one is
$$
\frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} (2x-10)^+dx 
  = \frac{1}{10} \int_5^{10} (2x-10)dx = 2.5
$$
and the left one is
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{100} \int_0^{10} \int_0^{10} (x+y-10)^+ dydx
 &= \frac{1}{100} \int_0^{10} \int_{10-x}^{10} (x+y-10) dydx \\
 &= \frac{1}{100} \int_0^{10} \left[ x(x-10) + 50 - (10-x)^2/2 \right] dx \\
 &= \frac{1}{100} \frac{500}{3} = \frac{5}{3}.
\end{split}
$$

the intuition is that in the $X+X$ case, knowing the left also fixes the right, but for $X+Y$ the left and the right are independent so there is more possibility for successful outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it make sense. However without calculation are we able to tell which side is larger, i.e. $E[(2X-10)_+] > E[(X+Y-10)_+]$ ?
from your intuition, it only tells that $X+Y$ has more possibility for successful outcomes, but it does not tell anything about the expected value of the overall outcome, which in this case is actually smaller than right hand side ($2x-10$).

Comment: @C.L. not sure, the devil is in the weighting of the successful outcomes with the probability measure.